# What does sign mean in this context?

Tags: machine-learning

[image]

From these lectures : https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~inabd171/wiki.files/lecture8_handouts.pdf

What does 'sign' mean in this context?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign (-, 0, +) of $<w, \psi(x)>$.

Since this answer has been flagged as too short, I'll add some characters:

1. Should numbers be signed?
2. Should book reports be at least 500 words?
3. Should someone on CV figure out a better solution to answer quality than number of characters?

Comment: It's this, right? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html

Comment: Yep. Adding more characters so I can comment.

Answer (score 1):

The sign or signum function is defined as

$$
\text{sgn}(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}~ x > 0,\\
0 & \text{if}~ x = 0,\\
-1 & \text{if}~x < 0
\end{cases}
$$